# Js file in browser devtools - being unformatted

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a js file.

When I edit or add any line of code and run my project and try to open my js file in browser's devtools source, I am seeing my js file unformatted.

```
    "All my js file code in one line"
```

I am not able to debug my js file.

How to resolve this. I want to get my complete js file (in browser) as formatted as in my code(work environment)

Comment: May I ask why you would want your JS file formatted in browser? Are you using webpack?

Comment: Yes, I am using webpack

Comment: Then this is what webpack actually does for you. It creates a dependency graph, thus processes your JS file. You might be intrested in https://webpack.js.org/contribute/debugging/

Comment: But It is working for rest of code... When I add something then it happens..Cant we resolve this ?

Comment: Can you share a repository?

Comment: I am having local project..If you can give solution about this.. it will be helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183364/discussion-between-neskews-and-a-d).